# Apply GPO to Group and Computers

Tags: group-policy

Trying to apply GPO to remove shutdown to a single user group [limited users] for any computer that a member of that group signs into AND a group of computers [laptops] for any user from any group that uses a laptop.

Intended results:

Desktop - limited user - no shutdown

Desktop - normal user - can shutdown

Laptop - limited user - no shutdown

Laptop - normal user - no shutdown

[image]

Comment: As this is a Windows-specific implementation question, I'm voting to migrate.

Comment: @schroeder: This post seems merely adapted to [sf] (6000 results for "group policy") than [su] (only 2000 results): handling Group Policy seems mere linked to corporate IT administration than consumer level configuration...